# Совмесная работа групп OptionButton

Tags: vba

Доброго времени суток!

Есть форма, на которой размещены две группы по два OptionButton и черыре TextBox. При выборе `OptionButton2` при установке метки на `OptionButton3` в `TextBox3` и  `TextBox4` производится запись из ячейки excel, однако если выбирать `OptionButton1` при установленной метке на `OptionButton3` в `TextBox3` должен стать пустым, однако это не происходит. Как сделать так, чтобы `OptionButton3` динамически реагировал на выбор `OptionButton1` или `OptionButton2`?

И вопрос №2 как при запуске формы сделать OptionButton1 установленным по умолчанию.